# Image not loading in webapp build using Python on Heroku

Tags: python, html, css, image, heroku

This is my directory structure that I push on heroku :

```
anon@ubuntu:~/projects/heroku$ ls -l
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 6 anon anon  4096 Dec 25 21:10 env
-rwxrwxr-x 1 anon anon  2404 Dec 30 02:39 myapp.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anon anon    21 Dec 25 23:11 Procfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anon anon   124 Dec 25 21:11 requirements.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anon anon 13490 Dec 29 16:32 image.jpg
```

The html in myapp.py that is returned when called is as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content_wrapper">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="Logo" />
        </div>
        <form action="/process" method="post">
            <input type="search" name="q" size="40" maxlength="200" placeholder="Enter your query...">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The image `image.jpg` is not loaded(broken). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Heroku doesn't like persistent files, since it operates your server in the cloud. Therefore, I would try not to include the image.jpg file directly in your Heroku repository. Rather, host the image on AWS (Amazon Web Services), and reference it in the markup.

[This tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) explains how to do that.

(It's possible that there is some way to convince Heroku to accept your image file. However, I'd still try to migrate to AWS.